# Can't release app or build web because of this package: blue_thermal_printer: ^1.1.9

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, thermal-printer

When I run this command

```
flutter run --release
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

I get this error in console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Infinix X656 in release mode...
/C:/Users/Bilal%20Saeed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/blue_thermal_printer-1.1.9/lib/blue_thermal_printer.dart:34:28: Error: Type 'Registrar' not
 found.
  static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Bilal%20Saeed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/blue_thermal_printer-1.1.9/lib/blue_thermal_printer.dart:34:28: Error: 'Registrar' isn't a
type.
  static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/Bilal%20Saeed/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/blue_thermal_printer-1.1.9/lib/blue_thermal_printer.dart:35:24: Error: Setter not found: 'i
nstance'.
    BlueThermalPrinter.instance = BlueThermalPrinter._();
                       ^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\All Data\Softwares\Latest Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
> Process 'command 'D:\All Data\Softwares\Latest Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 57s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          240.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

This file is also automatically generated with errors:

```
//
// Generated file. Do not edit.
//

// ignore_for_file: directives_ordering
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars

import 'package:blue_thermal_printer/';
import 'package:cloud_firestore_web/cloud_firestore_web.dart';
import 'package:cloud_functions_web/cloud_functions_web.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_for_web/connectivity_for_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_analytics_web/firebase_analytics_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth_web/firebase_auth_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage_web/firebase_storage_web.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast_web.dart';
import 'package:geolocator_web/geolocator_web.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter_web/google_maps_flutter_web.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in_web/google_sign_in_web.dart';
import 'package:image_picker_for_web/image_picker_for_web.dart';
import 'package:maps_launcher/maps_launcher_web.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences_web/shared_preferences_web.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher_web/url_launcher_web.dart';
import 'package:video_player_web/video_player_web.dart';

import 'package:flutter_web_plugins/flutter_web_plugins.dart';

// ignore: public_member_api_docs
void registerPlugins(Registrar registrar) {
  BlueThermalPrinterPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseFirestoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseFunctionsWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  ConnectivityPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseAnalyticsWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseAuthWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseCoreWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseMessagingWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FirebaseStorageWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  FluttertoastWebPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  GeolocatorPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  GoogleMapsPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  GoogleSignInPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  ImagePickerPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  MapsLauncherWeb.registerWith(registrar);
  SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  UrlLauncherPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  VideoPlayerPlugin.registerWith(registrar);
  registrar.registerMessageHandler();
}
```

As well I constantly see these errors in dart analysis :

```
error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:blue_thermal_printer/'. (uri_does_not_exist at [food_delivery_app] lib\generated_plugin_registrant.dart:8)
error: Undefined name 'BlueThermalPrinterPlugin'. (undefined_identifier at [food_delivery_app] lib\generated_plugin_registrant.dart:31)
```

However in debug mode, the app works fine.
And when I remove bluetooth_thermal_print package, it works fine as well too.
What could be the issue? How can I release my app with this package?

Answer (score 1):

Heads off to the developer of this package. I contacted him personally by going to his portfolio given on ***pub.dev*** and told him the situation. He updated the package from bluetooth_thermal_printer 1.1.9 to 1.2.0 in about minutes and it all worked smoothly once again....

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_thermal_printer) would not be properly installed.
Make sure the `pubspec.yaml` has the dependency listed:

```
dependencies:
  blue_thermal_printer: ^any
```

Then you can let fetch it fetch the files:

```
flutter packages get
```

---

While on the other hand, you're creating a web project
and then install a plugin, which possibly is rather for Android, iOS or HarmonyOS. `flutter config --no-enable-web` would disable the web support, which is a possible (even quite likely) candidate for the cause of that error message.

And even if some libraries may provide this kind of functionality in a web-browser
any kind of ESC/POS might be easier to handle without all the abstraction layers.

You may want to follow issue [#103](https://github.com/kakzaki/blue_thermal_printer/issues/103) ...which only confirms my educated guess.